# Threading (Does these threads exits or aborts itself?)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, delegates

I just wanted to ask a clarification about the program below:

```
foreach (Match match in MC)
{   
    string link = match.Groups["link"].ToString();
    if (link.Contains("ebay.de/itm/"))
    {
        int endIndex = link.IndexOf("?pt");
        link = link.Substring(0, endIndex);
        if (link != lastLink)
        {
            getEanPerLink = delegate
            {
                getEan(link);
            };
            new Thread(getEanPerLink).Start();
        }
        lastLink = link;
    }
}
```

It creates a lot of threads when the program loops. I just wanted to ask if those threads ends or exits itself. Or if not, how can I abort each of those threads created?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544528/does-a-thread-close-automatically

Comment: threads end by themselves once the task is complete.use Task class instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx. They are much cleaner,easy to use and has less overhead

Answer (score 3):

Each thread will end when the `getEan` method exits. If it does, then you don't have to do anything more, the thread and the `Thread` object will go away cleanly.

It's possible to abort threads, but it's not recommended because it throws an exception in the middle of whatever the thread is doing. The recommended way is to communicate to the thread that you want it to end, so that it can do that at a convenient place in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Make them as background threads than thay will be closed when you close or abort the running thread.

My recommnedition do not use threads in this; way this is a bad way to use thread.

if you r using .net 4.5 use async await
if you r using .net 4 use Task
if you r using .net 3.5 use ThreadPool
if you r using .net 2 backgroundWorker

Greertings,
Bassam