# How can I close multiple threads with an abort button?

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety

I know that similar questions have been asked and answered, but I do not have the experience or knowledge to apply what I have read in other threads to my current situation.

I have been developing a software program in c#, and I have very little background in programming (I'm a mechanical engineer). Basically , what my program does is tell syringes to move and push liquid through a flow meter to test if they run smoothly, and then I export the data into excel. I have up to five syringes going at once, and each one operates on its own thread because each flow meter needs its own COM port. My program needs to have an abort button that will kill and stop everything in its tracks.

I do not care if the data that I have gathered gets discarded as my excel file will not save itself at the time a thread would be closed.

I have read that it is not wise to use Thread.Abort, and nothing else I have tried seems to work every time. I have tried using flags placed throughout my code, but they don't seem to work properly for me.

My code looks something like this:

```
//within my "Run" button

if (cb1.Checked)
{
    Thread thread91 = new Thread(() => workThreadFunction91(coll[4], wb, xla, 
    timeRun, abort));
    thread91.IsBackground = true;
    thread91.Start();
}
//I then have that repeated four more times (one for each syringe)


private void workThreadFunction( ... )
{
testSyringes(...)
}

private void testSyringes( ... )
{
//code to send commands to syringes

while (time < timeRun)
 //code to communicate with syringes this is where my code runs for roughly 
a minute, and where I would need be able to abort should something go wrong. 
I call several other methods in here which send data to the flow meters, 
receive data from the flow meter, and export that data to excel.
}

private void abort()
abort = true; //(bool for a flag)

//code to reset syringes to initial position
```

That is basically a rough outline of my code in its current state. Any help would be appreciated, and I apologize if this question seems redundant in any way.

Comment: What is the expect behavior when you click the abort button?  Does it means that if syringe is moving to the position, it has to stop on the way and return to the initial position? and/or if it is pushing it has to stop pushing right away?

Comment: Yes, basically. The commands I will send to the syringe when abort is called are to stop them in their current position, reset settings on them (like speed and power), then send them back to the initial position. I can do that no problem with just a reset button, but I am unsure of how to close the threads that are still running in the background.

Comment: if you periodically check cancel flag in the method that has been assigned to thread, you can just return and thread will stop because there is no code to execute. [Does a thread close automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544528/does-a-thread-close-automatically)

Comment: Why not use the [BackgroundWorker Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle your thread creation/termination?  It is specifically designed for this type of work and it has a _cancellation_ feature that can be used.